# ClassCastException, casting Integer to Double

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
ArrayList marks = new ArrayList();
Double sum = 0.0;
sum = ((Double)marks.get(i));
```

Everytime I try to run my program, I get a ClassCastException that states: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Answer (score 57):

We can cast an `int` to a `double` but we can't do the same with the wrapper classes `Integer` and `Double`:

```
 int     a = 1;
 Integer b = 1;   // inboxing, requires Java 1.5+

 double  c = (double) a;   // OK
 Double  d = (Double) b;   // No way.
```

This shows the compile time error that corresponds to your runtime exception.

Comment: Hmm it is an old question.  Java 7 lets me cast Integer to *double* and the magic happens just how I expected: `Double km = (double) (metres *1_000);`

Comment: Just wondering why it won't be possible to convert Integer to Double? I have a piece of code that used to work, then suddenly stopped working and started throwing the same cast exception for some use-cases. An example of this failing is when the Integer value is 825842.

Answer (score 37):

Well the code you've shown doesn't actually include adding any Integers to the `ArrayList` - but if you *do* know that you've got integers, you can use:

```
sum = (double) ((Integer) marks.get(i)).intValue();
```

That will convert it to an `int`, which can then be converted to `double`. You can't just cast directly between the boxed classes.

Note that if you can possibly use generics for your `ArrayList`, your code will be clearer.

Comment: If you use `Integer.doubleValue()`, there is no need to cast `int` to `double`. `sum = ((Integer) marks.get(i)).doubleValue();` will be more succinct.

Answer (score 12):

The code posted in the question is obviously not a a complete example (it's not adding anything to the arraylist, it's not defining `i` anywhere).

First as others have said you need to understand the difference between primitive types and the class types that box them. E.g. `Integer` boxes `int`, `Double` boxes `double`, `Long` boxes `long` and so-on. Java automatically boxes and unboxes in various scenarios (it used to be you had to box and unbox manually with library calls but that was deemed an ugly PITA).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

You can mostly cast from one primitive type to another (the exception being `boolean`) but you can't do the same for boxed types. To convert one boxed type to another is a bit more complex. Especially if you don't know the box type in advance. Usually it will involve converting via one or more primitive types.

So the answer to your question depends on what is in your arraylist, if it's just objects of type Integer you can do.

```
sum = ((double)(int)marks.get(i));
```

The cast to `int` will behind the scenes first cast the result of `marks.get` to `Integer`, then it will unbox that integer. We then use another cast to convert the primitive `int` to a primitive `double`. Finally the result will be autoboxed back into a `Double` when it is assigned to the sum variable. (asside, it would probablly make more sense for sum to be of type `double` rather than `Double` in most cases).

If your arraylist contains a mixture of types but they all implement the `Number` interface (Integer, Short, Long, Float and Double all do but Character and Boolean do not) then you can do.

```
sum = ((Number)marks.get(i)).doubleValue();
```

If there are other types in the mix too then you might need to consider using the `instanceof` operator to identify them and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 8):

2 things to understand here -

1) If you are casting Primitive `interger` to Primitive `double` . It works. e.g. ***It works fine.***

`int pri=12; System.out.println((double)pri);`

2) if you try to Cast `Integer` object to `Double` object or vice - versa , It fails.

```
Integer a = 1; Double b = (double) a; // WRONG. Fails with class cast excptn
```

Solution -

```
Soln 1) Integer i = 1; Double b = new Double(i);
soln 2) Double d = 2.0; Integer x = d.intValue();
```

Answer (score 5):

specify your marks:

```
List<Double> marks = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

This is called generics.

Comment: If the ArrayList was full of Doubles then he would not get a ClassCastException.  The array must be full of integers, right?

Comment: @Gray - one `Integer` is enough ;)

Answer (score 3):

Changing an integer to a double

```
int abc=12; //setting up integer "abc"

System.out.println((double)abc);
```

The code will output integer "abc" as a double, which means that it will display as "12.0". Notice how there is a decimal place, indicating that this precision digit has been stored.

Same with  double if you want to change it back,

```
double number=13.94;

System.out.println((int)number);
```

This code will print on one line, "number" as an integer. The output will be "13". Notice that the value has not been rounded up, the data has actually been omitted.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum = Double.parseDouble(""+marks.get(i));
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation on why and how your code snippet does answer the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer x=10;
Double y = x.doubleValue();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code. How does it solve the problem?

Comment: It does convert x from Integer to Double

Comment: Integer wrapper class has doubleValue() method which return a double.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your ArrayList has integers in some elements. The casting should work unless there's an integer in one of your elements.

One way to make sure that your arraylist has no integers is by declaring it as a Doubles array.

```
    ArrayList<Double> marks = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you are casting using wrapper class, seems that they are incompatible types.

But another issue is that "i" is an int so you are casting the final result and you should cast i as well. Also try using the keyword "double" to cast and not "Double" wrapper class.

You can check here:

- [Java Docs Cast Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)
- [Stack Overflow Thread about ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

Hope this helps. I found the thread useful but I think this helps further clarify it.