# How can I add two double values together to form another double value(casting)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, logic

Basically, say if I have two double values as such:

```
 import javax.swing.JSpinner;
 import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;


public class UI  {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JSpinner stonesSpinnerImperial;
        JSpinner poundsSpinnerImperial;

        stonesSpinnerImperial = new JSpinner();
        poundsSpinnerImperial = new JSpinner();

        stonesSpinnerImperial.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 3, 31, 1));
        poundsSpinnerImperial.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0.0, 0.0, 13.0, 1.0));

        double imperial_stones = (double) stonesSpinnerImperial.getModel().getValue();
        double imperial_pounds = (double) poundsSpinnerImperial.getModel().getValue();
        double total_imperial_weight =  imperial_stones + imperial_pounds;

    }
}
```

However I get the following error:
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

I feel my logic behind this is flawed and any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've added as much as I feel is required.

Comment: What do `imperial_stones` and `imperial_pounds` have to do with `imperial_foot` and `imperial_inches`?

Comment: The variables in your first example do not match the ones in the second. Is that on purpose?

Comment: It has now been changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassCastException, casting Integer to Double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566336/classcastexception-casting-integer-to-double)

Comment: Like so?                                                         double total_imperial_weight =  (double) imperial_stones + (double) imperial_pounds;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#SpinnerNumberModel%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) that accepts `double` values; it uses `Double` internally. For example,

```
new SpinnerNumberModel(3d, 3d, 31d, 1d)
```

Addendum: Based on your updated code, consider casting to `Number`,

```
    double imperial_stones =
        ((Number)stonesSpinnerImperial.getModel().getValue()).doubleValue();
    double imperial_pounds =
        ((Number)poundsSpinnerImperial.getModel().getValue()).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply do:

```
  double imperial_stones = (Integer)stonesSpinnerImperial.getModel().getValue();
  double imperial_pounds = (Double) poundsSpinnerImperial.getModel().getValue();
  double total_imperial_weight = imperial_stones + imperial_pounds;
```

Note that you have to cast the object returned to a numeric wrapper class, not a primitive class, thus Double, not double, and Integer, not int.

Comment: It causes a mismatch, Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int, sorry had not realised your edit.

Comment: should I need to change the constructors to double as suggested by @trashgod ? If not what is the reasoning behind not doing it in that way?

Comment: @Banned: The constructors should use doubles if you want to display double numbers. If the numbers displayed will always be int values, then use ints in your constructor.

Comment: As you have mixed models, I'd [say](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10377606/230513) the parent, `Number`. +1

Answer (score 3):

If the dynamic type returned by `stonesSpinnerImperial.getModel().getValue()` is an `Integer` and you try to cast it to a `Double`, you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

In your case, the dynamic type is an `Integer` since you're using the constructor that accepts integers. Use the constructor that accepts doubles or restrict your computations to integer arithmetic.