# Java: ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting

I currently have a project, where I made an error which I can't figure out why it's giving me that error.

My structure:

```
Class: Variable (commands.lib.Variable);
Class: ImageLoader extends Variable (commands.lib.Variable);
```

Then I cast a Variable to an ImageLoader:

```
// There is a variable made with: Variable v = new ImageLoader();
public static Variable(commands.lib.Variable) getVariable(String value){...}
ImageLoader t = (ImageLoader)getVariable(ab[2]);
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: commands.lib.Variable cannot be cast to commands.variable.ImageLoader
```

So of course I googled **ClassCastException** and this post came out of the result: [Explanation of "ClassCastException" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/can-someone-explain-classcastexception-in-java)

Here someone explains:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Dog d = (Dog) a; // no problem, the type animal can be casted to a dog, because its a dog
Cat c = (Dog) a; // raises class cast exception, you cant cast a dog to a cat
```

So for my code it will look like this:

```
Variable a = new ImageLoader();
ImageLoader b = (ImageLoader) a; // This should work, but will throw a ClassCastException
Array c = (Array) a; // This should throw a error
```

So I'm a bit clueless.
I hope someone will help me, and fix the error.

Greetings,

Robin

Comment: I think that should work fine.. Can you show some code of your getVariable method?

Comment: Are you for sure returning the variable `v` that you created using `Variable v = new ImageLoader();`? Or returning something else?

Comment: Try stepping through the code to see what type of value t is. Or add some console output like `System.out.println(t.getClass().getName()`. That should give you some insight into what is being returned by getVariable().

Comment: Ok I found the problem, I didn't put the ImageLoader in the array. Instead I putted in a Variable.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the answer does not actually answer the question, but not deleting as the comments below are helpful in understanding of the underlying concept.

I have always been confused with this

but see

This statement

```
Variable v = new ImageLoader();
```

You are storing an object of `ImageLoader(Subclass)` to `Variable(SuperClass)` this is fine

But this statement

```
ImageLoader t = (ImageLoader)getVariable(ab[2]);
```

You are converting `Variable(superclass)` to `ImageLoader(SubClass)` 
This is not allowed in java, hence the error

Comment: No, this allowed. And according to your code, it will work perfectly.

Comment: I hope I have not got confused this time :)

Comment: You have. The cast will fail at runtime, if the superclass reference is not actually pointing to the same subclass instance that you are casting to. But, if it is pointing to the same instance that you are casting to, then it would work happily.

Comment: The problem is fixed. It was that not the correct class was putted in the Array.

Comment: @RohitJain yea you are right, its a a runtime time issue because of violating compilers compile time trust. by the way Jaap has answered his mistake in comment. He was giving a Variable reference. thus the compile time exception.. cool

Comment: @MukulGoel. Not compile time exception. It will be runtime exception. Compiler has no way to find, what is there inside the Variable.

Comment: @RohitJain , yea thats what I wrote : "a runtime issue of violating compilers compile time trust" , by Compile time trust i mean, that compiler trusts the programmer that the object being explicitly typecast will be of a compatible type.

Comment: @MukulGoel. Yeah that's perfectly a fine sentence. I just wrote that for your last statement that said: - `hus the compile time exception.. cool`

Comment: @RohitJain.. oh.. missed that..thanks

Answer (score 0):

In java you're allowed to cast a superclass to a subclass. I've done it before.
The problem was that the ImageLoader wasn't made. Where I thought it was made.