# Why compiler not give error or give warning for List l = new LinkedList<String>()

Tags: java, generics

Let me explain the scenario.

If i am not wrong, `Generics` in `java` are only for compile time type safety.
If i write

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();  // fine
list.add("test");  // fine
```

which is fine.But
If i write

```
List list = new LinkedList<String>();  // fine
list.add(9);  // fine
```

Here i have created `LinkedList` of String and `List` variable is pointing to `LinkedList`.
It is allowing to insert `integer` into `list`.

Now, `Generics` are related to types.Here `Type` is `List` and i have not written `generics` for that ie `List<String> list`
So writing `generics` at right side while creating `object` and not writing at left side doesn't make `List` `generic`. 
So why compiler doesn't give warning ar exception at run/compile time for following statement

```
List list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Is it useless to write such statement while using `Generics` in `java`.

Comment: The compiler does give a warning: _List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type safety with generics in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689477/type-safety-with-generics-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you will get a "rawtypes" warning if u write:

```
List list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: oh might give warning.I am using netbeans s it was not giving me warning for that statement

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar you need to enable warnings in the compiler settings

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar oh, sorry I'm not familiar with netbeans, I often use eclispe, but I think they both invoke javac to compile the code. So both of them should be able to display that message. Maybe there are some settings in netbeans to prohibit such warnings :) and I think Sean is right.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be instantiating the raw type `List` with the generic type `List<T>`.  The compiler will give you a *warning*; however, this can be done due to [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will display these warnings if you turn compiler warnings on using either

```
-Xlint:rawtypes,unchecked
```

or

```
-Xlint:all
```

See the [Non-Standard Options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#nonstandard) section of the [javac docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Answer (score 0):

From JDK 1.5, Java introduced Generics, which are used to define the type of the contents of a Collection.
If you initialize an ArrayList like this..

```
List list  = new ArrayList();
```

then the list can contain any type of data, It may be String, Integer or an Object. but if you want to define your List with a particular data type, than you can define it in angular brackets, like this..

```
List<String> list  = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will compile with raw type warning and you can insert Object of any type. It will also work on run time due to Type Erasure.

But this should be avoided since it doesn't make sense.