# classCastException please help me with real concept

Tags: java

when an object of subclass is assigned to the variable of a super class,why only those members
are accessible which are defined by the superclass

```
class A { 
    int i=10;
    void adsip() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int j=20;
    void bdsip() { 
        System.out.println(i+j);
    } 
}

class inherit4 { 
    public static void main(String[] x) { 
        A a=new A();
        B b=new B();
        System.out.println("b.i="+b.i+"b.j="+b.j);
        b.adsip();
        b.bdsip();
        a=b;
        System.out.println("a.i="+a.i);
        a.adsip();
    }
}
```

ABOVE CODE IS WORKING FINE
but after adding a.j and a.bdisp(); error is generated,as far as i know a & b in the above code represent 
refrence to memory allocation of objects of class A & B then why code is not able to access a.j and a.bdsip(); in above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > why only those members are accessible which are defined by the superclass

Because, at runtime, the superclass reference may be pointing to a superclass instance or instance of any class in the subclass hierarchy.

superclass has method m1, but subclass has method m1 and m2. You want to access m2 using a reference of superclass. But what if, at runtime, the reference is pointing to an instance of superclass (which does not have m2) ?

So the end result is that - 
At runtime, the only members that are guaranteed to be accessible using superclass reference are the ones defined in the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

**ClassCastException** - Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.

For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:

```
Object x = new Integer(0);
System.out.println((String)x);
```

Also please refer this thread.
[Can someone explain “ClassCastException” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/can-someone-explain-classcastexception-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In inheritance child can access parent data but the reverse is not possible. parent can't access child data. So here object of class A , a can't access Class B's method or data.

Comment: You say -parent can access child data but the reverse is not possible.  But A is the parent. It cannot access class B's method. Please clarify.

Comment: *In inheritance parent can access child data but the reverse is not possible* you're wrong. Children classes can access to `protected` and `public` data in parent class (it can also access to `default` data if the child class is in the same package as the parent class), but parent class has no idea of the specific data in the children classes...