# p:dataTable javax.el.ELException: selection="#{testBean.selectedBook} cannot convert from Object To Book

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a `single` selection table, when i select a row, this exception happens:

```
com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial javax.el.ELException: /Test.xhtml @18,79 selection="#{testBean.selectedBook}": Cannot convert [Ljava.lang.Object;@5b9b0639 of type class [Ljava.lang.Object; to class com.obs.model.Book
javax.el.ELException: /Test.xhtml @18,79 selection="#{testBean.selectedBook}": Cannot convert [Ljava.lang.Object;@5b9b0639 of type class [Ljava.lang.Object; to class com.obs.model.Book
```

`Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert [Ljava.lang.Object;@5b9b0639 of type class [Ljava.lang.Object; to class com.obs.model.Book`

Here is my Books table:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="singleDT" var="item" value="#{testBean.booksList}" selectionMode="single"
                 selection="#{testBean.selectedBook}" rowKey="#{item[0]}">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{testBean.onRowSelect}"/>
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{testBean.onRowUnselect}"/>

        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{item[0]}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Title">
            <h:outputText value="#{item[1]}"/>
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton process="singleDT" icon="ui-icon-search" value="View" action="#{testBean.showPlease}"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And this is `testBean` :

```
private List<Book> booksList;
private Book selectedBook;

public Book getSelectedBook() {
    return selectedBook;
}

public void setSelectedBook(Book selectedBook) {
    this.selectedBook = selectedBook;
}

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("row selected, " + event.getObject()); // displays [Ljava.lang.Object;@62699e1d
}

public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("row Unselected");
}

@Transactional
public List<Book> allBooks() {
// fill the list with hibernate
    return booksList;
}

//getter/setters
```

I assigned the selected row to `selectedBook`

Error is cannot convert from type `object` to `Book` type.

`selectedBook` variable type is `Book`, but which variable is `object` which causes this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain "ClassCastException" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/can-someone-explain-classcastexception-in-java)

Comment: @Kukeltje Not related to this.

Comment: If you learn how to debug, analyze stacktrace etc, you'll see it IS 100 related

Comment: You already got this exception and you were told about it. Why do you try to refer to this list - `List<Book> booksList` using array-like indices such as `item[0]`? The exception message indicates that an `Object[]` cannot be (type-)cast to `Book` (`[Ljava.lang.Object;` indicates `Object[].class` - `java.lang.Class` representing the class of array of `Object`s).

Comment: @Tiny Since i'm using hibernate with jsf, the hibernate query returns the `list Of arrays`.

Comment: The combination of jsf and hibernate is NOT the cause of the returning of the listof Arrays... You are since it is code you wrote and hibernate just does as insructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're victim of generic type erasure.

Your `List<Book> bookList` is **actually** being filled with `List<Object[]>`, not `List<Book>`. This is confirmed by the fact that `#{item[0]}`, `#{item[1]}`, etc in your JSF page didn't throw an EL exception. You knew that because of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975635/java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-while-iterating-over-a-pdatat and the answer in the linked duplicate.

You need to fix your Hibernate query in such way that it returns a real `List<Book>`, not a `List<Object[]>`. For example, you need to perform a `SELECT b FROM Book b` instead of `SELECT b.id, b.title FROM Book b` and set `Book.class` as return class when creating the query. You should not have need to add a cast on `(List<Book>)`. A bit sane IDE would show an unchecked cast warning on that. That should already have signaled that something is possibly wrong here.

After you've fixed your Hibernate query, you need to make sure that the below test case runs successfully without `ClassCastException`:

```
List<Book> books = callYourHibernateQueryHere();

for (Book book : books) {
    System.out.println(book.getTitle());
}
```

Only then you can use `rowKey="#{item.id}"`, `#{item.id}`, `#{item.title}`, etc.

Important note that this problem is technically unrelated to JSF. You would have had exactly the same problem when presenting Hibernate results in a different way, such as using `System.out.println()` as demonstrated above.

If fixing the Hibernate query is not an option for some reason, then you need to replace `Book` by `Object[]` over all place in your JSF managed bean. E.g. `List<Object[]> bookList`, `Object[] selectedBook`, etc. Needless to say that this is a terrible idea.

Comment: Its really complicated problem i ever seen!

Comment: That is it only when you're brand new to basic Java. It's not wise to already take a deep dive in Java EE while you aren't fluent in basic Java yet. True, Java EE looks exciting and challenging, but I warmly recommend to take a Java EE pause, put aside the Java EE projects, and take some weeks apart to learn some basic Java first. This way you get a better grasp on Java fundamentals such as generics and type erasure in this specific case. In fact, everytime you face an exception of `java.lang.*` package, you've "simply" a basic Java language problem.

Comment: You right, but actually i knew that the problem is about casting, but i would don't know why and how fix it! Then i post this question.

Comment: Because i have some more complicated query in some cases (for example joining multiple tables together and returning from multiple tables) , i can't return a `list if unit class`. So i have to do your second solution. correct?

Comment: You don't have to. It's your choice. I wouldn't recommend it as it only ends up in ugly code. If you can't figure the right Hibernate way, just ask a question to Hibernate guys (or just work through some basic Hibernate tutorials).

Answer (score -3):

If you look at the FULL stacktrace, you'll most likely see that the error is in YOUR code. You can and should investigate a classcast exception easily yourself

As a sidenode:

- `value="#{testBean.booksList}"` refers to a method in your bean that is NOT shown in the bean code you posted (but very, very relevant, since an individual item in that list is what is in selection)
- Do you have any clue how the `p:dataTable works`? I think not. Look at the PF showcase and check all the differences functionalities of it and check the source code and compare with yours
- You should not only learn some basic jsf/jpa but basic developer skills

Comment: `booksList` is not shown in bean? Are you kidding? Just keep open your eyes.

Comment: The getter is NOT there, just the field. For all we know your getter is wrong. Learn to post MCVE.

Comment: You are welcome... And I don' t mind getting downvoted on answers like this (I even expected it and hoped for it, since my answer deserves it, so it means SO works to a certain extend). What *you* do not get is that by posting partial code, do not do basic investigation, you greatly diminish your chance of actually getting help. And that in future posts you might get ignored. Bon chance...