# org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorSite cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSite

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am porting eclipse 3 RCP on Eclipse 4. I am getting runtime exception `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Here is the code snippet

```
public FamilyEditorSite(MultiPageEditorPart multiPageEditor, IEditorPart editor) {
            Assert.isNotNull (multiPageEditor);
            Assert.isNotNull (editor);
            this.multiPageEditor = multiPageEditor;
            this.editor = editor;

            // Point for runtime exception
            PartSite site = (PartSite) this.multiPageEditor.getSite();
            //IWorkbenchPartSite site = multiPageEditor.getSite ();
            IServiceLocatorCreator slc = (IServiceLocatorCreator )site.getService (IServiceLocatorCreator.class);
            context = site.getModel().getContext().createChild("FamilyEditorSite");
            ....
            ....
    }
```

This code is similar to library class [MultiPageEditorSite](https://github.com/qualidafial/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/part/MultiPageEditorSite.java).

But still I get runtime exception as follows

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorSite
>   cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSite
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.family.FamilyEditorSite.(FamilyEditorSite.java:136)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.family.FamilyEditor.createSite(FamilyEditor.java:653)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:236)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.addPage(FormEditor.java:325)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:213)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.addPage(FormEditor.java:308)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.family.FamilyEditor.addPages(FamilyEditor.java:177)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:362)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:243)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.reconfigurePages(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:393)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.doPartInitialization(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:660)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.access$8(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:548)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor$6.execute(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:804)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2157)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2153)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.createPages(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:809)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:362)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:141)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:327)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1246)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:69)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4732)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
>         at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:488)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:454)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:705)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:392)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1145)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3210)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$23(WorkbenchPage.java:3125)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$9.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3102)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3066)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3056)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:541)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:500)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenFileAction.openFile(OpenFileAction.java:99)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenSystemEditorAction.run(OpenSystemEditorAction.java:99)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.OpenActionGroup.runDefaultAction(OpenActionGroup.java:133)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.MainActionGroup.runDefaultAction(MainActionGroup.java:330)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator.handleOpen(ResourceNavigator.java:787)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator$6.open(ResourceNavigator.java:499)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:853)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:850)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1142)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1249)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
>         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:331)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
>         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:331)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index out of bounds
>         at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4422)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.getItem(CTabFolder.java:836)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.family.FamilyEditor.pageChange(FamilyEditor.java:504)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1101)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:603)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.family.FamilyEditor.setActivePage(FamilyEditor.java:581)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:366)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:243)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.reconfigurePages(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:393)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.doPartInitialization(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:660)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.access$8(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:548)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor$6.execute(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:804)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2157)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2153)
>         at org.acmestudio.ui.editor.AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.createPages(AcmeStudioMultiPageEditor.java:809)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:362)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:141)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:327)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1246)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:69)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4732)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
>         at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:488)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:454)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:705)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:392)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1145)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3210)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$23(WorkbenchPage.java:3125)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$9.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3102)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3066)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3056)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:541)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:500)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenFileAction.openFile(OpenFileAction.java:99)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenSystemEditorAction.run(OpenSystemEditorAction.java:99)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.OpenActionGroup.runDefaultAction(OpenActionGroup.java:133)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.MainActionGroup.runDefaultAction(MainActionGroup.java:330)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator.handleOpen(ResourceNavigator.java:787)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.ResourceNavigator$6.open(ResourceNavigator.java:499)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:853)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:850)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1142)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1249)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
>         at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
>         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:331)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
>         at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
>         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:331)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.acmestudio.armani.editor.rules.RuleHelper.shouldEvaluate(RuleHelper.java:139)
>         at org.acmestudio.armani.editor.rules.IgnoreRuleInterceptor.adjustResult(IgnoreRuleInterceptor.java:15)
>         at org.acmestudio.acme.type.verification.TypeChecker.performTypecheck(TypeChecker.java:206)
>         at org.acmestudio.acme.type.verification.TypeChecker.runTypecheckLoop(TypeChecker.java:342)
>         at org.acmestudio.acme.type.verification.SimpleModelTypeChecker.runEvaluationLoopOnce(SimpleModelTypeChecker.java:455)
>         at org.acmestudio.eclipse.core.environment.TypeCheckingJob.run(TypeCheckingJob.java:34)
>         at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question has major formatting and content problems. Please edit it, and highlight what you are trying to do, what should be happening, and what the error is. Also, take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain "ClassCastException" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/can-someone-explain-classcastexception-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSite` is in an **internal** package and you should not be trying to use it.

`MultiPageEditorSite` is not based on `PartSite` so you cannot cast from one to the other.

You can get the `IEclipseContext` for the part using:

```
IEclipseContext context = (IEclipseContext)getSite().getService(IEclipseContext.class)
```