# how to cast dbcp connection to oracle connection?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I need cast PoolableConnection  to OracleConnection  in runtime but I don't know how to do it.
becasuse i got classCastException and if all classes extends Connection, can I do it ?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/907368/2664200

Comment: Why do you need to use `OracleConnection`? It used to be that this was required in order to use BLOBs effectively, but that's no longer the case. What's the use case that requires the cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to cast to the DBCP specific Connection class and from there retrieve the inner Oracle connection:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection;

DelegatingConnection dc = (DelegatingConnection)conn;
OracleConnection oc = (OracleConnection)pc.getInnermostDelegate();
```

If you are using Tomcat's built-in copy of DBCP then the import you will need is:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection;
```

Or you can use the connection pooling built into the Oracle JDBC driver implementation. This returns an Oracle connection. A simple setup would be:

```
<Resource auth="Container"
          connectionCacheName="CXCACHE"
          connectionCacheProperties="{MaxStatementsLimit=5,MinLimit=1, MaxLimit=1, ValidateConnection=true}"
          connectionCachingEnabled="true"
          description="Oracle Datasource"
          factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
          name="jdbc/TestDB"
          user="default_user" 
          password="password"
          type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl"
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast only if the object you're casting actually *is* an instance of the class you're casting it to.  If you're getting a `ClassCastException` that's not the case.

All classes that extend `Connection` can be cast to a `Connection`, but not necessarily to each other.