# How can i call the child method after downcasting parent object to child object?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, downcast

I have Request class which is a parent class and AddressRequest class which extends Request.

```
public AddressRequest extends Request
{

    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```

I have the input data in the Request object. how can I set the userId to the same object by calling the setter method in the child class.

I downcasted the Request object to AddressRequest object and tried calling the setter method which is throwing CTE.

```
Request request= new AddressRequest ();
request=(AddressRequest )inputRequest;
request.setUserId("11");
```

How can i call the child method after downcasting object?

Answer (score 1):

So, essentially what you're doing here is dynamic dispatch. by specifying

```
Request request= new AddressRequest ();
```

what you're doing is saying this Request is an AddressRequest, but by calling it a Request you are unable to access the method for AddressRequest.

A quick solution would be to Safe Cast -> If you're sure that you're dealing with and AddressRequest, then
cast request as

```
(AddressRequest) request.setUserId("11");
```

Comment: You might need to write `( (AddressRequest) request).setUserID("11");` so the compiler understands it needs to cast the object and then run the method.

Comment: Also for more information about class cast exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/can-someone-explain-classcastexception-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You cannot downcast ***superclass reference type*** which is an ***instance of superclass***.

You can downcast ***superclass reference type*** which is an ***instance of subclass***.

You are stuck with case #1 where your `inputRequest` is of type `Request` and an instance of `Request` i.e

```
Request inputRequest = new Request();
```

You can't cast this to `AddressRequest`, if you try to do so you will get `ClassCastException` as object of `Request` is neither subclass of `AddressRequest` nor compatible with it.

But if your `inputRequest` is of type `Request` and an instance of `AddressRequest` then you would have succeeded. i.e

```
Request inputRequest = new AddressRequest();
```

You can fairly cast this to your subclass(`AddressRequest`) and apply it's methods.

**Summary:**

```
Request req1 = new Request();
Request req2 = new AddressRequest();
Request req3 = new SubClassOfAddressRequest();
```

You can't cast `req1` to `AddressRequest` : req1 is object of Request and it is not compatible with AddressRequest.

You can cast `req2` to `AddressRequest` : req2 is object of AddressRequest and is compatible with AddressRequest.

You can still cast `req3` to `AddressRequest` : req3 is an object of AddressRequest's SubClass(this is kind of upcasting).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea, Thanks. This was helpful. I tried using a parameterized constructor for AddressRequest and intialize it with Request object. Its working now.

Comment: How you are initializing AddressRequest with Request type Object? Do you mind to share constructor here?