# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to "Activity" on ImageButton Android

Tags: android, listview, android-imagebutton

I have an array adapter and inside it an Imagebutton listener calling an activity.

Above my ListView I have and a input search of a ListView item.

When I search for an item by typing the initial letters and Click on Image Button

```
viewHolder.discounts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DisplayDiscounts.class);
            intent.putExtra("CustomerId",String.valueOf(cu.getId()));
            ((Customers) getContext()).startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

I get java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to "ActivityName"

How I can fix this?

Can I stop the input search when item found?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of "ClassCastException" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cast here is the problematic part:

```
((Customers) getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```

just drop the cast and use `getContext().startActivity(..)` instead.

Comment: Now I get Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

Comment: are you calling this from a service? what's the context?

Comment: from array adapter

Comment: but what if the single adapter is used in for multiple Activities?

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass an `Activity` reference to your activity or try `((Customers) v.getContext()).startActivity(intent);`