# ByteBufferAsShortBuffer cannot be cast to java.nio.FloatBuffer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got the following error while running project.Can anyone help me??

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.ByteBufferAsShortBuffer cannot be cast to java.nio.FloatBuffer**

Here is my code:

```
Buffer[] samples = frame.samples;
                       if (aaD.track.getChannelCount() == 1)
//For using with mono track
                        {
                            Buffer b = samples[0];
                            fb = ((ByteBuffer) b.rewind()).asFloatBuffer();//here is error
                            fb.rewind();
                            smpls = new float[fb.capacity()];
                            fb.get(smpls);
                        }
```

Please help

Comment: Cannot efficiently be done with Buffers AFAIK. So ByteArrayOutputStream, DataOutputStream or such.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You cannot do the cast you're trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/can-someone-explain-classcastexception-in-java

Comment: Then please give solution for casting @Christopher Schneider

Comment: @NikulRao Google is generally your best buddy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was not quite as elegant as I had thought. I see why you asked. I could not find a way to do what you want to do without allocating extra memory.

This is a quick and dirty way to move the `ShortBuffer` to a `FloatBuffer`.

```
   public FloatBuffer fBuffer(){
        ShortBuffer sb = ShortBuffer.allocate(4);
        sb.put(new short[]{256,256,128,64});

        short[] shortArr = sb.array();  
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(shortArr.length * 2);
        bb.asShortBuffer().put(shortArr);

        return bb.asFloatBuffer();
    }
```

If performance is critical and you're doing tons of these operations, it's a good idea to look at using native (C/C++) code to manipulate bytes directly or use something like Renderscript.