# Cast Exception with custom GlSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, classcastexception, glsurfaceview

Hi guys i declared a custom GlSurfaceView in this way

```
public class Render extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
```

and in an other class i initializate it using:

```
render= (Render) view.findViewById(R.id.gl);
```

but at runtime the vm generate this exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.opengl.GLSurfaceView cannot be cast to com.pugtests.depugscompany.openglprove.Render
```

why ? Can anyone explain to me my mistake and help me to fix it.. sorry for my english and thanks to everyone.

Comment: Are you sure you're casting the instance you think you're casting? As in, you're casting something which isn't a `Render` at all.

Comment: @Andy Turner what he tries to cast is the Class, whis is extended by his Renderer.

Comment: @GAlexMES nope. It's not an instance of his class. If that were the case, the exception message would be `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pugtests.depugscompany.openglprove.Render cannot be cast to ...`. (Except that that wouldn't occur, because the cast would be allowed).

Comment: @Andy Turner, ah I guess I missunderstand you. You mean, that he is adding a GLSurfaceView to his view and is casting this to an Renderer?

Comment: Not sure, but sounds like you add a GLSurfaceView instead of Render in your layout-xml.

Comment: Sorry but if render extends GlsurfaceView is it a GlSurfaceView and so a View so if the superclass is the same why there is a error??

Comment: There is an error because you are trying to cast a GLSurfaceView to Render. Yes, Render extends GLSurfaceView and therefore it is a View. But the other way round does not apply. Not every GLSurfaceView can be cast into Render.

Comment: Why sorry but i don't understand as well the reason..can you explain to me why? Thanks indeead

Comment: This is a bit too much for the comments on SO. Search for Inheritance to find some explanations. An example is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm).