# Converting an object to a string array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am having trouble converting an object to an array. I have already searched for this problem but none of it was a solution for me.

I am having an error of

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2 cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

this is my code:

```
 for (int i=0; i < list.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
                Object item = list.getModel().getElementAt(i);
                System.out.println("Item = " + item);   

                //String[] srcFiles = (String[]) item;

                File finalFile = new File(srcFiles[i]);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(finalFile);
```

How can I convert `Object item` to a String array?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do? Why do you think `(String[]) item` would work? Do you understand how casting works?

Comment: `item` is of type `Win32ShellFolder2` which you cannot just automatically turn into a `String[]`.

Comment: Show the `list` declaration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of "ClassCastException" in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

Comment: i want my `Object item` to be a String array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2` is a subclass of `File` you can just write:

```
Object item = list.getModel().getElementAt(i);
System.out.println("Item = " + item);   
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream((File)item);
```