# Unable to Cast Map into Java Class

Tags: java, collections

```
public class Model extends LinkedHashMap<String, Object>{

}

LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = //instance of LinkedHashMap

Model model = (Model) map  // Exception.
```

when I'm trying to cast `LinkedHashMap<String,Object>` into my Model class I'm getting class cast exception.

I'm basically using user defined method which expect Model as an argument that's why I'm casting my map into Model class

Comment: What is `//some value`? Is it `new Model()` or `new LinkedHashMap()`?

Comment: Just because a `LinkedHashMap` *can* be a `Model`, doesn't mean it always is. What do you gain by downcasting when you could just instance your `Model` class instead?

Comment: Of course is `new LinkedHashMap()`

Comment: Which API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `LinkedHashMap` where `Model` is expected, therefore you cannot cast.

Presumably Model has additional methods and more functionality than LinkedHashMap. Even if you did not add anything new in `Model` class yet, Java assumes that you will.

Possible solution: change

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = //instance of LinkedHashMap
```

to

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = //instance of Model
```

Another solution: change the code that uses `Model` class to use `Map` instead.

Still another approach: do not derive `Model` from `Map`, have `Model` own a `Map`. Change the code accordingly.

In general, you need to learn more about OO programming, especially the modern sort that deprecates inheritance in favor of aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that because `Model` is not an `instanceof LinkedHashMap`.  Think in terms of memory allocation.  What have you actually done?  You have allocated enough memory for a `LinkedHashMap` but NOT for a `Model`.  The compiler is trying to save you from yourself.

Comment: `Model` is a type. It's never an instance of anything. Memory allocation isn't the issue here, it's type relationship. This answer completely missed the point, which is that downcasting, i.e., narrowing conversion of a reference always (!) risks a `ClassCastException`, as the JLS points out. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6

Answer (score 0):

API Specifications for the ClassCastException says:

Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.

```
class P {
}
class C extends P {
}

P p = new P();
C c = (C) p;//java.lang.ClassCastException; Runtime Exception
```

If you really want to do it. You do it in this way:

```
LinkedHashMap map = new Model();
        map.put("one", "1");

        Model model = (Model) map; // Exception.
        System.out.println(model);
```

referece: [Explanation of "ClassCastException" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)