# JFXTreeTableColumn problems with date field in the JFoenix Library

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, jfoenix

It will not let me compile because it says that I can not cast the data, this is the error that I get when compiling my project:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsCZA.png)

When removing the column from the Date, my project works with all the fields in the Table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of "ClassCastException" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

Comment: You need to show the erroneous code (relevant parts) and the error message in the question itself ***as text***. Posting this info as image only is strongly discouraged and posting only a link to the info makes the question off topic.