# ClassCastException while trying to typecast one object to another

Tags: mockito

I'm trying to unit test a class which has something like this

```
Obj1 var = (Obj2) var2;
```

When I try to run unit test on these using mockito, I get an error from mockito saying it can't be typecasted from one form to another. How do I fix this?

Comment: show your test class

Comment: There's nothing significant there. I just want to know if there is a way to overcome this limitation. The error message is  "java.lang.ClassCastException: *.InvoiceItem$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$96e8b6e6 cannot be cast to *.InventoryInvoiceItem"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of "ClassCastException" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

Comment: You need to show at least the specific type used to create `var2` and how it is related to `Obj1`.... with the current code it's impossible to say for sure... we can just guess here...