# Is there a way to change the generic type of an ArrayList without creating a new temporary ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Can we change the generic parameter type of an `ArrayList<?>()` after having created it, say, for example from `Arraylist<Integer>()` to `ArrayList<String>`, without using a temporary ArrayList to hold the elements and then copy them back to the new list?

Comment: Why not just use an `ArrayList<Object>()`? But better yet, why do you need to do something like this?

Comment: Yeah, there are easier alternatives and design choices, than to be doing this. I was just curious to know if it's possible. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Depending on what you mean with temporary ArrayList you could use some nice lambda's to map/convert them.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists a valid conversion between the two types, this can be possible. For example:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
List<Long> longs = ints.stream().map(val -> (Long) (long) (int) val).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(longs);
```

**Output:**

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

This takes a list of `Integer`s, applies a conversion function to make each of them a `Long`, and collects the converted values into a list of `Long`s.

The reason this works lies in the conversion function:
`val -> (Long) (long) (int) val`. This function takes an `Integer`, unboxes it to an `int`, widens it to a `long`, and boxes it to a `Long`. Therefore, the function defines the conversion from `Integer` to `Long`. This can also apply to other instances where you know the type. For example, if you have the following case:

```
class A {}
class B extends A{}
List<A> as = Arrays.asList(new B(), new B());
List<B> bs = as.stream().map(val -> (B) val).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(bs);
```

It will also compile, and output something like the following:

> [B@681a9515, B@3af49f1c]

The reason that this works is that, inside the conversion function (`val -> (B) val`), you cast all values within the list of `A` to the type `B`. However, this will throw a [ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907367/5699679) in the case that the value you cast is not truly an instance of `B`.