# How to convert an Object to a custom DTO

Tags: java, list, object, dto

Im having some issues trying to convert a List of Object to a custom DTO. However, all the answers that i found are focused on converting Entities or POJ0s to DTO. How can i do this in either some kind of iteration, or even manyally accesing all the Object properties?

Right now i have something like this that throw some casting errors, but idk if changing datatypes would work or if i should try something else.

```
List<Object> ls = myDAO.getSomethingFromDB();
List<MyDTO> ls2 = new ArrayList<MyDTO>();
    for(Object o : ls){
        ls2.add((MyDTO) o);
    }
```

Also, first StackOverflow questing, sorry if im asking something dumb or in a bad way.

Comment: have a look at [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert `Object` to `MyDTO` until unless `myDAO.getSomethingFromDB();` is returning list of `MyDTO`

Learn more about `ClassCastException` here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html
[Explanation of ClassCastException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

if you really want to convert to MyDTO then you need to create new MyDTO object then set the values to this object.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this, here is one of those ways using [Java Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
List<MyObject> objects = // Get objects from database

List<MyDto> dtos = objects.stream().map(myObj -> {
            MyDto newDto = new MyDto();

            // Set your properties here, in this example i'm setting a name and description:
            newDto.setName(myObj.getName());
            newDto.setDescription(myObj.getDescription());
            // Repeat for every property

            return newDto;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am using the `map` function to create a new DTO with the same properties as my object in the list.