# AnimatedNavHost "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set" (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a single activity app with different screens represented by composables. I am using navigation component to handle screen navigation.

My navigation component has AnimatedNavHost as:

```
 val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()
    AnimatedNavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Constants.SPLASH
        ) {
            composable(Constants.SPLASH) {
                Splash(navController = navController)
            }
```

I get the following error on running the app:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost$lambda-3(AnimatedNavHost.kt:323)
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost(AnimatedNavHost.kt:158)
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost(AnimatedNavHost.kt:85)
```

But the code works fine on using 'NavHost' instead of 'AnimatedNavHost'.

My Accompanist navigation dependency is:

```
 implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.16.1"
```

My Kotlin compiler extension version is:

```
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.2'
```

My Kotlin version is:

```
'1.5.21'
```

I have been looking for the solution since hours, not able to find it.
Please help me solve this.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation of ClassCastException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

Comment: @ElPrimo I have chosen the best answer for this question. That answer answers my question.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not relevant because the exception is in library code.  I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your accompanist version is outdated. Make sure you're using [latest version](https://github.com/google/accompanist/releases), which is `0.20.0` right now.