# FragmentContextWrapper cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner

Tags: android-studio, android-camera, lifecycleowner

I get the following error. Can you help me?

> E/VRCameraViewCameraXImpl: Use case binding failed
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper
> cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner

The libraries used are as follows:

`build.gradle`

```kotlin
// CameraX core library using camera2 implementation
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.0-alpha01'
// CameraX Lifecycle Library
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.0-alpha01'
// CameraX View class
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.0-alpha01'
//RTMPX
implementation 'io.github.luohaohaha:rtmpx:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation of ClassCastException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/explanation-of-classcastexception-in-java)

Comment: @Martin Zeitler  No,thank you.